# z-index in menu with ul don't work

Tags: jquery, z-index

I try to make a simple menu.

[`jsFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/awzster/wqDnt/3/)

Problem:

I want to menu `level2.*` display under menu level1.

But z-index doesn't work as well.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>

    <body>
        <div class="menu">
            <ul class="l1">
                <li> <a href="#">Menu level 1</a>

                    <ul class="l2">
                        <li> <a href="#">menu level 2.1</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">menu level 2.2</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">menu level 2.3</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

javascript

```
$.fn.xMenu = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
        var menu = $(this);

        menu.find('ul.l1').children('li').children('a').bind('click', function () {
            window.console.log(this);
            menu.find('ul.l2').hide();
            menu.find('ul.l1').children().removeClass('menu-borderd');
            $(this).parent().addClass('menu-borderd');
            $(this).parent().children('ul.l2').each(function () {
                $(this).addClass('active').show();
            });
        });
    });
}

$('.menu').xMenu();
```

CSS

```
.menu a:hover {
    background-color:#e4ebf8;
}
.menu a {
    outline:none;
}
.menu ul.l1 {
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0 0 0 10px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 50;
}
.menu ul.l2 {
    list-style: none;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #C3D1EC;
    margin-top: -10px;
    display:none;
    padding: 0px 16px 0px 0;
    z-index: 49;
}
.menu ul.l1 li {
    padding:0;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 50;
}
.menu ul.l2 li {
    padding:0;
    float:none;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    width:100%;
}
.active ul {
    display:block;
}
.active a {
    background-color: white;
    display: block;
    height: 29px;
    padding: 0 8px 0 8px;
    position:relative;
}
.active a:hover {
    background-color:#e4ebf8;
}
.active ul.l1 a {
    border: 0 !important;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 #CCCCCC;
    border:0;
    width: 100%;
}
.menu-borderd {
    border-color: #C3D1EC;
    border-style: solid solid none;
    border-width: 1px 1px 0;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 5px #CCCCCC;
}
```

Comment: Say my genetically modified giant gorilla escapes and smashes up the servers JSFiddle runs on. What happens? Your question becomes useless, that's what. Please post the code _in your question_ so it's of use to future visitors. My giant gorilla is called Bazooper, for those wondering

Comment: I don't understand the negative votes -- example code was given just not on the question

Comment: @Hogan Read my comment. Now that the OP has put their code in the post I've removed my downvote

Comment: @Bojangles - that was me that put the code in.  Something you could have done. :D

Comment: @Hogan So it was. I skimmed the page and made assumptions, but the point still stands; if JSFiddle goes away the question is useless without code in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `z-index:-100;` to `.menu ul.l2` and remove the other `z-index`

Here is a working **[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7E3qC/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Your negative margin-top on `.menu ul.l2` is causing it to ride above the first `li`. If you change this to `0px` it should be fine.

Please see this corrected [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wqDnt/4/).